# Dinamically Populate a Product Field As Checkboxes(allow multiple choices) in Gravity Forms

Tags: gravityforms

Is possible to add a Product Field in Gravity Forms and set Field Type as Checkboxes?, that way will allow the multiple choices(Products) option. Want to avoid tedious repetitions steps for clients in order to select different kind of products.

In addition would like to implement a Product Option Field that be dinamically populated from an List Field with 2 columns if is possible.

Finally but still important, want to implement in a field dinamically populated (used as Dropbox) a way to set as Ordering Option the Group By statement, it only allows me ASC/DESC or Random options.

Tried with Populate Anything Addon, did not work.